# How to add new rows to DataTable only under specific columns?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I've got a DataTable, dt2, where I'm trying to add new rows (in the else block of the code below). I cannot simply add the rows within the foreach loop (which I tried with the line `dt2.Rows.Add(newRow);`) because that screws up the loop counter or something and causes the following error: **"Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute."**

So I tried storing the new row values in a List and then adding the List to the table outside of the loop. This works in the sense that it compiles and it does add something; unfortunately it doesn't take the correct values or column locations but instead displays this crap: **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]**

[image]

Also, the information *should* be displayed in the 3rd, 4th, and 5th index columns under Target_Folder, Target_File, and Target_Checksum, not under Baseline_Folder.

How do I store and display the correct values under the correct columns?

```
foreach (DataRow drow in dt2.Rows)
{
    if (drow["BASELINE_FILE"].ToString() == filename)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        newRow = dt2.NewRow(); // newRow is a DataRow I declared up above
        newRow[3] = directory;
        newRow[4] = filename;
        newRow[5] = checksumList[j];
        newRow[6] = "Missing";
        //dt2.Rows.Add(newRow); 
        // can't add here because that increases the number of rows and screws up the foreach loop
        // therefore need to find way to store these values and add outside of loop
        newFiles.Add(newRow); // newFiles is a List
    }
}
dt2.Rows.Add(newFiles); // this doesn't work properly, doesn't take correct values
```

Comment: i m facing same problem can any body give the solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, but something along these lines should work:

```
DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
foreach (ListItem item in newFiles.Items)
{
dr[3] = item[3].ToString();
dr[4] = item[4].ToString();
etc.
}
```

If you need more guidance, let me know and I'll look harder at it.

Comment: where am I adding that? after the foreach loop?

Comment: newFiles is defined outside the loop, right? If so, you can do it after the loop.

Comment: it says that DataRow dr = new DataRow(); is inaccessible due to its protection level and is throwing a compile error

Comment: Sorry, it should've been DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow(); And I neglected to mention you'll need to loop through the list. foreach (ListItem item in newFiles.Items)etc

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you really want to do :

```
DataRow[] drx = dt2.Select(string.Format("BASELINE_FILE = '{0}'" , filename));

if (drx.Length == 1)
 {
    // do stuff with drx[0]

 }
 else
 {
    newRow = dt2.NewRow(); // newRow is a DataRow I declared up above
    newRow[3] = directory;
    newRow[4] = filename;
    newRow[5] = checksumList[j];
    newRow[6] = "Missing";
    dt2.Rows.Add(newRow); 
 }
```

This way you don't need to loop through the rows.

Comment: what is this doing? Can you explain that first line?

Comment: @user1985189 the select function checks the rows against a certain condition and returns a collection of rows. it works like sql select.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to go through each row in the existing grid, this should do it for you.  This way currentRows isn't being modified while loop is running as it will be a shallow copy of that list.

```
var currentRows = from row in dataTable.Rows select row;
foreach (var row in currentRows)
{
    if(doStuffCondition){ doStuff();}
    else{
      DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
      newRow[1] = newValue;  //repeat until values are loaded
      employeesDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
 }
```